# How to import a npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import, package.json

I have published a npm package called sum . which have just main.js file:

```js
export function sum (a , b){
    return a+b
}
```

My package.json is like this :

```json
{
"name":"sum",
"version":"1.0.0",
"description":"simple npm package",
"main":"./main.js",
"module":"./main.js"
}
```

I installed it in another directory and import it:

```js
import {sum} from "sum"
alert(sum(1,2))
```

but it gave this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "sum". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Answer (score 1):

locally you need to spacify the path of the module main.js file on importing

like this

```
import {sum} from '/path/to/direc/main.js'
```

or

you can add the package in your local npm modules and test.

for this you have to run.

```
cd ~/projects/your-pkg      # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/curr_proj     # go into some other package directory.
npm link package name       # link-install the package
```

Comment: yes , I know but I am telling you that I have published the sum package and installed it with npm install sum